# Passing an argument to git alias not working

Tags: git, git-alias

I created the following alias on Windows 10 to issue a `commit -am <commit message>` command. I used the the `$1` token to register an argument, but it is not working.

`git config --global alias.cam 'commit -am $1'`

Issuing the following command returns the error message below:

`git cam "test commit"`

**Error Message:**

`fatal: paths 'test commit ...' with -a does not make sense`

How do I make this work? I researched how to use arguments in git aliases, but none of the resources offers a simple solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just `commit -am`.  It puts the args you supply at the end of the rewritten command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-alias%5D+arguments

Comment: @jthill That works, but now it just displays the untracked files when I issue ```git cam "test commit"```. Nothing is staged or committed. If I issue the add and commit commands separately, it works fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the rule for Git beginners: do not use `git commit -a`.

This is the rule for advanced Git users: do not use `git commit -a` unless:

- you would run `git add -u` before `git commit`, and
- you know that the repository is not using a badly written pre-commit script that will misbehave in the presence of `git commit -a`.

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527674/passing-an-argument-to-git-alias-not-working#comment119357501_67527674):

> @jthill That works, but now it just displays the untracked files when I issue git cam "test commit". Nothing is staged or committed. If I issue the add and commit commands separately, it works fine. Why is that?

The problem here is that `git commit -a` is not like `git add` followed by `git commit`.  It's more like `git add -u` followed by `git commit` (but even then, still not *exactly* the same).  Specifically, `git add -u` will only update files that Git *already knows about*.  The `u` in `-u` stands for *update*, i.e., don't add any untracked files, but do update all tracked ones as appropriate.

You have an untracked file that you'd like to add.  You *must* use `git add` *without* the `-u` option to do this.  (Technically there are several other commands that could get you there, but `git add` is the one to use.)

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I just used the following alias and it works: ```git config --global alias.cam '!git add . && git commit -m'```. And the command ```git cam "test commit"``` now works.

Comment: Why doesn't the following alias work? ```git config --global alias.rma '!git config --global --unset alias.$1'```. Issuing ```git rma cam``` doesn't remove the ```cam``` alias but doing this works: ```git config --global --unset alias.cam```.

Comment: With the `$1` variant, you're literally running `git config --global --unset alias.cam cam`. (Use `GIT_TRACE=1` in front of a shell command to have Git show you what it's doing.) Next, check [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Exercise: what does `--unset name.of.option value_regex` do, based on the documentation? What does the regular expression `cam` match?

Comment: After doing the exercise, consider the following general rule. To make Git shell aliases behave, write them as *shell functions*, using the template: `alias = !f() { command1; command2 "$1"; shift; command3 "$@"; }; f`. Another exercise (fairly hard unless you've done some shell programming): what's going on here? (If you have not written programs in sh/bash, there's a lot of reading to do!)

Comment: I did the following and it's working now. Thanks again for the feedback. ```git config --global alias.rma '!sh -c "git config --global --unset alias.$1"'```

Comment: @rajndev: That does work, yes. Note that passes all arguments to the `sh -c` command. What does `sh -c "echo foo" bar baz quux` do? (Try it and see, and/or read the `sh` documentation. Try it with `sh -c 'echo $@'` as well.) The function method is more efficient, too, because it spawns one `sh` to interpret the alias without spawning a second `sh -c` to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass the aliased git command to a shell command. This way, the `$1` argument will not be appended again to the end of the command, causing it to succeed.

`git config --global alias.cam '!sh -c "git commit -am $1"'`

Or simply leave out the `$1` argument token:

`git config --global alias.cam '!git commit -am'`

But, keep in mind that `commit -a` only applies to *tracked* files that need their modifications staged. So a better approach would be:

`git config --global alias.cam '!git add . && git commit -m'`